# PHP syntax question: What does the question mark and colon mean?

Tags: php, syntax, conditional-operator

```php
return $add_review ? FALSE : $arg;
```

What do question mark and colon mean?

Comment: well spotted, almost the same title too.

Comment: Not to nitpick but isn't it the colon you want to know about and not the semicolon? Talking of colons, is this comment a tad anal? :-)

Comment: I'll edit, it will help anyone searching....

Comment: This question has a better title than the one it is marked as a duplicate of...

Comment: Speaking from the future, 6 years later, this is the question I landed at. Thanks @PaulDixon for thinking of the people searching in the future.

Comment: @GregHewgill The accepted answer is better, even if the question is the same.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

This is the PHP [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (also known as a conditional operator) - if first operand evaluates true, evaluate as second operand, else evaluate as third operand.

Think of it as an "if" statement you can use in expressions. Can be very useful in making concise assignments that depend on some condition, e.g.

```
$param = isset($_GET['param']) ? $_GET['param'] : 'default';
```

There's also a shorthand version of this (in PHP 5.3 onwards). You can leave out the middle operand. The operator will evaluate as the first operand if it true, and the third operand otherwise. For example:

```
$result = $x ?: 'default';
```

It is worth mentioning that the above code when using i.e. $_GET or $_POST variable will throw undefined index notice and to prevent that we need to use a longer version, with `isset` or [a null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) which is introduced in PHP7:

```
$param = $_GET['param'] ?? 'default';
```

Comment: Since PHP 5.3, it is also possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to TRUE, and `expr3` otherwise.

Comment: is there a situation in php7+ where you would want to use `?:` instead of `??`?

Comment: @user When `expr1` is not `NULL` but falsy instead (`FALSE`, `0`, etc).

Answer (score 22):

It's the ternary form of the if-else operator. The above statement basically reads like this:

```
if ($add_review) then {
    return FALSE; //$add_review evaluated as True
} else {
    return $arg //$add_review evaluated as False
}
```

See here for more details on ternary op in PHP: http://www.addedbytes.com/php/ternary-conditionals/

Comment: Sorry trying to understand this @cristianivascu how would this read - <?php echo ($active_page == 'home' ? 'active' : '');?>

Comment: If the value in $active_page equals the string 'home' it would print out 'active', otherwise it would print an empty string.