# PHP question mark

Tags: php

```
$hideCode = $likesObj->isAlreadyLikedByUser(facebookUID()) ? 'style="display:none;"' : '';
```

Can anyone explain to me what that question mark does in this line of code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is called the [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), and it's common to several languages, including PHP, Javascript, Python, Ruby...

```
$x = $condition ? $trueVal : $falseVal;

// same as:

if ($condition) {
    $x = $trueVal;
} else {
    $x = $falseVal;
}
```

One very important point to note, when using a ternary in PHP is this:

> Note: Please note that the ternary operator is a statement, and that it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of a statement. This is important to know if you want to return a variable by reference. The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a return-by-reference function will therefore not work and a warning is issued in later PHP versions.
>   <sub>[source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)</sub>

Comment: ?: 
"There's also a shorthand version of this (in PHP 5.3 onwards). You can leave out the middle operand. The operator will evaluate as the first operand if it true, and the third operand otherwise." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276909/php-syntax-question-what-does-the-question-mark-and-colon-mean#1276912

Answer (score 4):

Actually this statment is representing a [Ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), a conditional expression:

```
// works like:    (condition) ? if-true : if-false;

$hideCode = $likesObj->isAlreadyLikedByUser(facebookUID()) ?  'style="display:none;"':'';
```

in your case `$hideCode` will have `style="display:none;"` value if

```
$likesObj->isAlreadyLikedByUser(facebookUID())
```

will return true, else it will be null or empty.

Answer (score 3):

It's a shorter version of a IF statement.

```
$hideCode = $likesObj->isAlreadyLikedByUser(facebookUID()) ? ' style="display:none;"':'';
```

if in fact :

```
if($likesObj->isAlreadyLikedByUser(facebookUID()))
{
   $hideCode = 'style="display:none"';
}
else
{
 $hideCode = "";
}
```

For the purism :

It's representing a [Ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

Comment: Lol the #1 answer is exaclty what I say. Thx for the down vote... completly useless down vote.

Answer (score 3):

This is the simple if-then-else type logic:

```
(condition) ? (if-true-value) : (if-false-value)
```

so in your case, the condition is checked (i.e. has the page already been liked by the user); if yes (true condition), then `style="display:none;"` is printed so that whatever the element you're using is not displayed.  Otherwise, an empty string is printed, which is the equivalent of not printing anything at all, naturally.

Answer (score 0):

It is the ternary operator: it means

if `$likesObj->isAlreadyLikedByUser(facebookUID())` is true assign  `style="display:none;` to the variable, otherwise assign `''`

Answer (score 0):

It's part of a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). The first part is the conditional of an if-else statement. After the question mark is the "if" block, and after the colon is the "else" block.

Answer (score -1):

> $hideCode = $likesObj->isAlreadyLikedByUser(facebookUID()) ? 
>   'style="display:none;"':'';

This is the same as the following:

```
if ($likesObj->isAlreadyLikedByUser(facebookUID()))
{
    $hideCode = 'style="display:none;"';
}
else
{
    $hideCode = '';
}
```

Comment: This isn't contributing anything that hasn't already been said.