# "Build" $_GET['xyz'] from variables

Tags: php, variables

I have two variables:

```
$method = "_GET";
$var = "id";
```

I now need this:

```
$parameter = $_GET['id'];
```

I tried something like this:

```
$parameter = ${$method.'[\''.$var.'\']'};
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: $parameter = "$".$method."[".$var."]";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$data = $$method;
$parameter = $data[ $var ];
```

The following:

```
$method = '_GET';
$var = 'id';

$data = $$method;
print_r($data);
echo $data[ $var ];
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => test
)
test
```

Assuming the query string is `?id=test`

@Leggendario pointed out an interested caveat: This won't work outside of the global scope, even though $_GET is a super global. You have to add `global $$method` before you can reference `$$method` in a function.

Also, it turns out [there is a one-liner that will do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27783901):

```
${$method}[$var];
```

Comment: or just `${$method}[$var];`

Comment: I just added the code I used to test this. Please take a look and let me know if there is still a problem.

Comment: it works when I use it in a blank php script, but it doesnt in my class.. need to figure that out i guess

Comment: @Philip You need to add `global $$method;` before that.

Comment: before what? where exactly?

Comment: before `$data = $$method;`. You need that because you're not in global scope. And `_GET` is global.

Comment: Leggendario is correct, I was a bit surprised since $_GET is a super global, but it doesn't look like this works within the scope of a function unless you use `global $$method`.

Comment: another way to do this without `global $$method;` is `$GLOBALS[$method][$var];`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not concentrating any strings to form the variable name, just put it in `{}`:

```
$parameter = ${$method}[$var];
```

---

Another possible solution, since the only two methods are `_GET` and `_POST`, is to use a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6583737/1234256) instead:

```
$parameter = $method == "_GET" ? $_GET[$var] : $_POST[$var];
```

Comment: PHP is interpreting $$method[$var] as ${$method[$var]} so you get an illegal string offset.

Comment: @mtinsley My mistake. Fixed!

Comment: Nice update on making it work with a one liner. I didn't think there was a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>That's basically a variable-variable:</strike>

```
$method = '_GET';
$var = 'id';

$foo = $$method[$var];
```

Turns out to not work at all... Yay php consistency, and I've learned my new thing for today.

This works:

```
php > $_GET['id'] = 'foo';
php > $method = '_GET';
php > $offset = 'id';
php > echo ${$method}[$offset];
foo
```

and turns out to have been documented: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php   search for "ambiguity"

Comment: This method does not work. PHP is trying to reference a variable with the name `$method[$var]`. You get an illegal string offset notice because `$method` is _GET.

Comment: thats what I get, any ideas?

Comment: @Philip see my answer, it isn't a one liner but I tested it and it works.

Comment: Figures... yay for php parse consistency. Had no idea that arrays couldn't be var-var'd...

Comment: I like your answer the best still because you have corrected the ambiguity mistake with proper referencing to the PHP docs as the supported way to prevent ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
filter_input(constant("INPUT" . $method), $var);
```

The [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function let's you reference the `INPUT_GET` constant value for the [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function by string name.

Using this method, you are retrieving the value and have the option to filter/sanitize it using the [filter values](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) on this page for extra security all in one setup.