# How to set a default page id?

Tags: php

I am trying to display content depending on page id, however when I add nothing to the url, so just index.php I get an error saying that `$p` is not defined, how can I give this var a default value that's outside the switch case?

```
<?php
$p = $_GET['p'];
switch ($p) {
    case 1:
        $content1 = new login();
        $content = $content1->displayLogin();
        break;

    case 2:
        echo "ID is 2";
        break;

    case 3:
        echo "ID is 3";
        break;

    default:
        $content1 = new dbconnection();
        $content = $content1->displayTable();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: So really, you're asking how to assign a value to a variable?

Comment: $p = ""; does not work @PatrickQ same for giving it value 0 or 20 (outside switch case)

Comment: Read the link in the first comment. You are trying to access an element of an empty array.

Comment: Read your error carefully.  Is it saying that the _variable_ `$p` is not defined or is it saying that the _index_ 'p' is undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want to make `$p` have a default value if `$_GET['p']` is not defined.

You can do it like this:

```
$p = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'defaultValue';
```

or, if you're on PHP 7:

```
$p = $_GET['p'] ?? 'defaultValue';
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
$p = $_GET['p'];
```

With:

```
$p = !empty($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : default_id_value_here;
```

Comment: In your replaced line, don't forget to assign that `!empty?` result to $p.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$p = $_GET['p'] ?? <default value>; // e.g 1 or 3 etc.
```

Read more about it at this question: [PHP syntax question: What does the question mark and colon mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276909/php-syntax-question-what-does-the-question-mark-and-colon-mean)